# Buffer option not available to select in Editor menu of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, editing

[image: screenshot]

I need to use the Buffer in the Editor menu of ArcMap, but it is unavailable.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You **must** have to select your polygon(s) to make 'buffer' option enable in Editor Toolbar. You may use 'Select Features' tool or alternatively select your  polygon(s) via 'Edit tool' to enable buffer option.

[image]

You may also use attribute table for polygon feature selection or use 'Buffer' tool available in ArcGIS to buffer around input polygons.